# Efficient thread safe observer design pattern without expensive copying

Tags: c++, design-patterns

What's the efficient way to implement a thread safe observer design pattern ?

Using the following code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

class Subject {
public:
    void addObserver(Observer* observer) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        observers_.push_back(observer);
    }

    void removeObserver(Observer* observer) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        // Remove the observer from the vector
    }

    void notifyObservers() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        for (Observer* observer : observers_) {
            observer->update();
        }
    }

private:
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::vector<Observer*> observers_;
};
```

it's not recommended to hold a lock and call a callback !
Also coping the list of observers each time I send a notification I not efficient also.

Is there an efficient way to achieve thread safety.

Comment: Copying a vector of pointers of reasonable size can be quite cheap. The problem is how to handle a case where an observer removed iteself (and possibly deallocated) after the copy was done but before it was used to perform the callback. Using `std::shared_ptr<Observer>` instead of raw pointers might help manage the lifetime.

Comment: Using a vector of weak_ptr can help to avoid calling callback when holding a lock. But it need to copie much more data each event.

Answer (score 1):

vector isn't all that great when you have to do removals so I would use std::list.

I've done similar things in the past, and the thing is to decouple administration locks for adding/removing from the actual notification.
Please ask questions if you have them

```
#include <mutex>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

struct Observer
{
    void notify() 
    {
        std::cout << "notified\n";
    }
};

class Subject
{
public:
    // keep a list of observers to add, so it is seperate
    // from the observers list notifyObservers may be iterating over
    void addObserver(Observer* observer)
    {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(add_mutex_);
        observers_to_add_.push_back(observer);
    }

    // keep a list of observers to add, so it is seperate
    // from the observers list notifyObservers may be iterating over
    void removeObserver(Observer* observer)
    {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(remove_mutex_);
        observers_to_remove_.push_back(observer);
    }

    // keep a list of observers to remove, so it is seperate
    // from the observers list notifyObservers may be iterating over
    void notifyObservers()
    {
        // one lock to prevent multiple threads
        // from concurrently accessing notification logic
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(notify_mutex_);

        // local scope to keep lock on adding observers short    
        {
            std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(add_mutex_);
            observers_.insert(observers_.end(), observers_to_add_.begin(), observers_to_add_.end());
            observers_to_add_.clear();
        }

        // local scope for short lock on removal administration
        {
            std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(remove_mutex_);
            for (const auto& observer : observers_to_remove_)
            {
                observers_.remove(observer);
            }
            observers_to_remove_.clear();
        }

        for (auto& observer : observers_)
        {
            observer->notify();
        }
    }

private:
    std::mutex remove_mutex_;
    std::mutex add_mutex_;
    std::mutex notify_mutex_;
    std::list<Observer*> observers_;
    std::list<Observer*> observers_to_add_;
    std::list<Observer*> observers_to_remove_;
};

int main()
{
    Observer observer1;
    Subject subject;
    subject.addObserver(&observer1);
    subject.notifyObservers();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice can be quite useful when moving elements between std::list

Comment: @PiotrNycz Thanks, I've never seen that function before. But it would not change much in this case :) (lines with insert and clear would become one call to splice)

Comment: It changes a lot - with splice you can re-use internal list nodes - no need for series of deallocations/allocations